# 13.04 runs poorly on ASUS X201E-DH01

Tags: installation, 13.04

I just installed 13.04 on my [ASUS X201E-DH01](http://shopping.yahoo.com/1077190744-x201e-dh01-116-led-notebook-intel-celeron-b847-110-ghz-black/specs) and it runs terribly. Super slow and no mouse. Could somebody help? I used to have 12.10 on it and it worked fine. I think 13.04 should be able to run because when I run it off of the usb, it works like a charm.

Comment: I'm running 13.04 on an Asus X201E-DH01 right now and it runs fine. Do you have any other symptoms you can edit into your question? If you upgraded, you may want to try a clean install, possibly into a new partition for testing.

Answer (score 2):

12.04.2 is the prefered OS on this Laptop as it supports all the Hardware and UEFI boot.ASUS themself ship their Laptops with this Version.

12.10 works fine, but so will 12.04.2 as both use the same kernel.

13.04 with kernel 3.8 is full of bugs and not a good Option at all ( on any machine ) .

Grub commandline Settings to try for this machine :

make FN-Keys work :  "acpi_osi=" or "acpi_osi=Linux"

save power for GPU : "pcie_aspm=force"

for kernel 3.8+ : "acpi_osi=!Windows 2012"